# Loop performance

Tags: python, performance, loops

In a given challenge, the function below was requested to be executed in less than 1 second:

```
from time import perf_counter


def loop(seed, n):
    tic_0 = perf_counter()

    r, m = seed, 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        m += 362437
        r = (r ** 2 + m) % 4294967296
        r = (r // 256) % 65536

    print('\nTotal Runtime = {:.6f}'.format(perf_counter() - tic_0))
    return r

loop(366, 11223300) -> 1 second limit
```

The only tip provided is: a compiled program can run up to 200 times faster than a mathematically identical script in the Python interpreter.

As the next term of the loop is dependent on the previous term, the use of the "multiprocessing" module was not useful to me. Could you give me any idea how this tip can be applied?

Code execution currently takes about 10 seconds.

Comment: Another Tip: vectorization

Comment: Also, use `timeit` rather than printing

Comment: Pure Python wouldn't allow an optimization of the requested scale. There are things like Cython or numba to compile Python(-like) code to machine code.

Comment: if it helps, here is the link: [link] (https://edabit.com/challenge/9bTzMLzKk7AaCqJtA)

Comment: Note that `% 4294967296` means consider the first 32 bits, i.e. it can be replaced by `& 0xFFFFFFFF`. The same goes for `% 65536`, which considers the first 16 bits, i.e. use `& 0xFFFF`

Answer (score 1):

Well, that only took ***4.04s*** on my box but I got an instant reduction to ***2.5s*** by simply changing `r ** 2` into `r * r`. I could further get it down to ***1.6s*** by using bit shifting and bitwise operations, such as changing:

```
r = (r * r + m) % 4294967296
r = (r // 256) % 65536
```

into:

```
r = (r * r + m) & 0xffffffff
r = (r >> 8) & 0xffff
```

Then, when you realise which bits are going to survive those two operations, you can turn that into the single expression:

```
r = ((r * r + m) & 0xffff00) >> 8
```

That drops the time down to ***1.33s***, easily doubling the speed (a reduction of ***67%*** in elapsed time).

---

If you switch to something like [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/), you can get even more improvement:

```
from numba import jit
from time import perf_counter

@jit()
def loop(seed, n):
    r, m = seed, 0
    for i in range(n):
        m += 362437
        r = ((r * r + m) & 0xffff00) >> 8
    return r

tic_0 = perf_counter()
x = loop(366, 11223300)
print('\nTotal Runtime = {:.6f}'.format(perf_counter() - tic_0))
print(x)
```

That brings the execution time down to a rather minuscule ***110ms***, well within your one-second limit, and roughly a ***90%*** improvement in elapsed time over the original.

And that actually includes the time taken to initially JIT-compile the code, so the improvement is even better on subsequent calls. By changing the code so that we JIT the function first, the time drops to ***20ms***, a saving of ***99.5%***:

```
x = loop(1, 2)
tic_0 = perf_counter()
x = loop(366, 11223300)
print('\nTotal Runtime = {:.6f}'.format(perf_counter() - tic_0))
print(x)
```

That's on par with similar C code, which you could probably treat as the benchmark for performance. For example, the following C code executes in ***27ms***, a reduction of about ***99.3%*** in time taken (that's with default optimisation; using `-O3` gives about ***18ms***):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    unsigned long r = 366, m = 0;
    for (int i  = 0; i < 11223300; ++i) {
        m += 362437;
        r = ((r * r + m) & 0xffff00UL) >> 8;
    }
    printf("%ld\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @jotav, I've inserted a Python-specific improvement, though it's not *pure* Python - it requires the `numba` package to be installed. I'm assuming that's okay since the hint given mentioned a "compiled program". Of course, the C code still blows it out of the water and, despite the competition being Python only, people should generally select the best tool for the job :-)

Comment: Amazing, thank you. While "-either properly compiling Python", would that speed up even more? Do you have a link where they teach you how to do it?

Comment: @jotav, I've never used a tool to specifically compile *all* of Python. The ones that give you an executable tend to just bundle the interpreter and libraries into a package that is standalone but still interpreted. Things like Numba are good in that they can remove specific bottlenecks without affecting the rest of your code. Since I meant that comment to specifically refer to Numba, and I've now added a section for it, I've removed the comment.

Comment: figured out how to make it even faster, it is possible to delete m + =362437 and change  r = ((r * r + i*362437) & 0xffff00) >> 8, and the loop for i in range(1, n+1):

Comment: @paxdiablo that Numba library is neat, thanks! I'd never heard of it before.

Comment: @jotav: you would have to time it to see if it would be faster. It doesn't appear to have any substantial impact based on my testing.

Comment: @paxdiablo tested it on the version before applying the "numba" module and the time dropped from 2.038528s to 1.896857s on my pc.

Comment: You are measuring compilation+execution time (first call) for your Numba function. The runtime itself (eg. second call) is only 15-20ms.

Comment: @max9111, I didn't think of that, it does indeed bring it down to about 20ms. Have incorporated that into the answer.

Comment: Maybe it is also worth to mention that the performance of the original code is quite the same as your optimized version (compiled by Numba). r**2-> r*r is done by Numba automatically https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/master/numba/cpython/numbers.py#L207) Integer division by a constant and remainder calculation is optimized by the LLVM-backend https://zneak.github.io/fcd/2017/02/19/divisions.html

Answer (score 0):

Is cheating allowed?

The initial seed value is not stored, so if the value of `r` ever hits zero that means the initial seed value is meaningless.

The `& 0xffff` operation takes place every loop, and the chance that a randomly picked number happens to have its trailing digits as `0x...0000` (resulting in `0x...0000 & 0xffff = 0`) is `(1/16)**4 = 65536`.

That happens 187 times for those given initial values, which happens to be every 60017 iterations (pretty close).

That means you only need to calculate the last million or so values to have an "optimized" loop that is observationally identical:

```
from time import perf_counter

def loop2(seed, n):
    r, m = seed, 0

    for i in range(max(1, n - 1000000), n+1):
        r = ((r * r + i * 362437) >> 8) & 0xffff

    return r

tic_0 = perf_counter()

for init in range(1000):
    result = loop2(init, 11223300)
    assert result == 1738

print('\nTotal Runtime = {:.6f}'.format(perf_counter() - tic_0))
```

These 1000 loops all gave the same answer and took 315 seconds to run on my machine, for an average time of 0.315 seconds.

Comment: Very good observation, I will try to use it. There are several tests with varying intervals, I just put this one to guide the question.